# Request.get() returns only one page of bitbucket repos

Tags: python, request, bitbucket

I want to list all the repos from bitbucket but the request.get() in the below code returns only one page.

```
import json
import requests
#from bitbucket.bitbucket import Bitbucket
from bitbucket.client import Client
rs = requests.get("https://bitbucket.org/owner/")
client= Client('username','password','owner')
response= client.get_repositories()
print(response)
```